# parse json file from SD card in android app

Tags: android, json, android-sdcard

I have an array of JSON objects on an SD card.

I get the file contents like this:

```
File yourFile = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/test.json");
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
        String jString = null;
        try {
            FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
            /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
            jString = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
          }
          finally {
            stream.close();
          }
```

The structure is like this:

```
[{"name":"john"},{"name":"fred"},{"name":"sam"}]
```

and I want to be able to parse them to make a listView. In JavaScript I can get them as an AJAX request and then do

```
var people = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
```

and then loop through the array. But I am a complete novice at java - I have found example code that does each of those things separately but I can't put them all together. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to explain what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String[] from = new String[] {"name"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name};
List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

try 
{
    JSONArray names = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    Log.i("MyList","Number of names " + names.length());
    for (int j = 0; j < names.length(); j++) 
    {
         JSONObject jsonObject = names.getJSONObject(j);
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));
         fillMaps.add(map);
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, fillMaps, R.layout.result, from, to);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here `mListView` is your predefined `ListView`.
Feel free to share your doubts here, if any.

Comment: haven't tried it, but other code I've tried never gets past JSONArray names = new JSONArray(jsonString); - Value [{ of java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: no, my bad - this will probably work too. Will test and get back

Comment: That error is due to your String. Every double-quote should be preceded by a \ to mark it as a part of string and not the beginning or end of a string. Replace your string by `[{\"name\":\"john\"},{\"name\":\"fred\"},{\"name\":\"sam\"}]`

Comment: yes, I saw that but it doesn't seem to make much difference. the decoder adds those in anyway. But thanks for the full code on making the listView - that saved me from posting about another 20 questions, I'm sure :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have it as a string, you should be able to parse it to a `JSONObject` with something like this:

```
JSONObject jObj = null;

// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    Log.i(TAG, "JSON Data Parsed: " + jObj.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

I would also put the data (in your example) into an array, so it appears as something like:

```
{"names": [{"name": "john"},{"name": "fred"},{"name": "sam"}]}
```

And then to read your object again, you can put it into an array (or something else I guess) with something like this:

```
// create an empty list
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
// pull the array with the key 'names'
JSONArray array = jObj.getJSONArray("names");
// loop through the new array
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    // pull a value from the array based on the key 'name'
    l.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```

Hope at least some of this helps out (or at least points you in the correct direction).  There are PLENTY of resources on here though, too.

**EDIT:**

Read up on JSON formatting.  `[]` denotes array and `{}` denotes object, so you have an array of objects. That is why I recommended changing your format.  If you are set on your format, either go with what Mr.Me posted for his answer, or just split your string at special characters and put them into an array that way.

Comment: thanks for the input. And believe me, I have looked at lots of posts and offered solutions. The thing is that I can't change the structure of the JSON (or I could, but it would kind of defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do). I am getting a string, but maybe the wrong way? I have updated my post to show how I get the file contents. The original code you posted gives me an error: Value [{ of java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: yeah, I know the difference between an array and an object. That's why so few of the examples I've seen have been of any use. I'm not set on my format, but I don't create it and so I didn't want to have to go in and manually change it. It seems like this works, though: jObj = new JSONObject().put("names", jString); (completely untested in the wider app, but logs OK). If I'm missing something please let me know, otherwise thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the above JSON structure represents a JSONArray and not a JSONObject

[JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

So after getting your `jstring` just do this

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jString);
for(int i=0; i< array.length(); i++){
  JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
  String value = obj.getString("name");
 }
```

Comment: nope. That gives me Value [{ of java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray (and the same thing happened when I tried to loop through the array made by jObj = new JSONObject().put("names", jString); )

Comment: the code is 100% fine, please double check your data representation, it would be best if you add data from your file to the question

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Versioning problem :O thanks, Mr.Me